# Ventana modal jQuery no cierra

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Buen día compañeros estoy en un problema con `jQuery`, estoy realizando un sistema con una ventana modal, lo que pasa es que no me cierra. Este es el código:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#frmPaciente').dialog({
       autoOpen:false,
       heigth:310,
       width:400,
       modal:true,
       buttons:[{
            text: "Crear",
            click: function(){
                alert("crear");
            }
       },
       {
           text: "Cerrar",
           click: function(){
               $(this).dialog('close')
           }
       }]
    });
});
```

El primer botón crear lo hice con un `alert` para verificar si funcionan los botones, por eso identifico que el problema es:

El `$(this).dialog('close')` no me funciona, y por otro lado la ventana no me sale centrada.

[image: ejecucion de la aplicacion]

Muchas gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

aquí el código `html`:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" content="text/html" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <title>Sistema Gestion Odontologica</title>
        <link href="Vista/css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Vista/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Vista/js/script.js"></script>
        <!--Archivos Necesarios para el dialog-->
        <link type="text/css" href="Vista/jquery/dialog/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="Vista/jquery/dialog/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--fin de archivos necesarios para el dialog-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="contenedor">    
            <div id="encabezado">
                <img src="Vista/imagenes/odontologia.png" width="100%" height="150px" >
            </div>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="index.php">Inicio</a></li>
                <li class="activa"><a href="index.php?accion=asignar">Asignar Cita</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?accion=consultar">Consultar Cita</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?accion=cancelar">Cancelar Cita</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="contenido">
                <h2 style="width:100%">Asignar Cita</h2>
                <form id="frmAsignar" method="POST" action="index.php?accion=guardarCita">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Documento del Paciente</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="asignarDocumento" id="asignarDocumento"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                            <input type="button" name="asignarConsultar" value="Consultar" id="asignarConsultar" onclick="consultarPaciente()">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><div id="paciente"></div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Medico: </td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="medico" name="medico">
                                    <option value="-1" selected="selected">---Seleccione el Medico---</option>
                                    <option value="12345">12345 Camilo Robledo</option>
                                    <option value="67890">67890 Esteban Salgado</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Fecha: </td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Hora: </td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="hora" name="hora">
                                    <option value="-1" selected="selected">---Seleccione la hora---</option>
                                    <option>8:00:00</option>
                                    <option>8:20:00</option>
                                    <option>8:40:00</option>
                                    <option>9:00:00</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Consultorio: </td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="consultorio" name="consultorio">
                                    <option value="-1" selected="selected">---Seleccione el Consultorio---</option>
                                    <option value="1">1 Consultas1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2 Tratamientos2</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <input type="submit" name="asignarEnviar" value="Enviar" id="asignarEnviar">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>    
            </div>    
        </div>
        <!-- ventana modal-->
        <div id="frmPaciente" title="Agregar Nuevo Paciente">
            <form id="agregarPaciente">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Documento</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="pacDocumento" id="pacDocumento" readonly="readonly"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nombres</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="pacNombres" id="pacNombres"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Apellidos</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="pacApellidos" id="pacApellidos"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fecha de Nacimiento</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="pacNacimiento" id="pacNacimiento"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sexo</td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="pacSexo" name="pacSexo">
                                <option value="-1" selected="selected"><---Seleccione Sexo---></option>
                                <option>m</option>
                                <option>f</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Así esta funcionando ahora:

[image: aparece en la esquina inferior izquierda y sin los botones]

agrego la imagen de las extensiones:

[image: bibliotecas]

Comment: Intenta con `#frmPaciente` en lugar de `this`

Comment: No funciona cambiando el identificador

Comment: pon tu codigo `html`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probando tu código en un `fiddle`, y viendo la documentación de `Jquery UI`, creo que tu problema es la versión de `JQuery UI` que estas utilizando, noté que estas usando la 1.9.2, y probé con esa versión y efectivamente no cierra la ventana, pero probando con la versión mas nueva 1.12.1, centra el `dialog` y ademas cierra la ventana con el botón.

Aquí un ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#frmPaciente').dialog({
       autoOpen:false,
       heigth:310,
       width:400,
       modal:true,
       buttons:[{
            text: "Crear",
            click: function(){
                alert("crear");
            }
       },
       {
           text: "Cerrar",
           click: function(){
               $(this).dialog('close')
           }
       }]
    });
      $( "#create-user" ).button().on( "click", function() {
      $('#frmPaciente').dialog( "open" );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" content="text/html" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <title>Sistema Gestion Odontologica</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <!--terminacion de archivos necesarios para el dialog-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="contenedor">
            <div id="encabezado">
                <img src="Vista/imagenes/odontologia.png" width="100%" height="150px" >
            </div>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="index.php">Inicio</a></li>
                <li class="activa"><a href="index.php?accion=asignar">Asignar Cita</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?accion=consultar">Consultar Cita</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?accion=cancelar">Cancelar Cita</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="contenido">
                <h2 style="width:100%">Asignar Cita</h2>
                <form id="frmAsignar" method="POST" action="index.php?accion=guardarCita">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Documento del Paciente</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="asignarDocumento" id="asignarDocumento"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                            <input type="button" name="asignarConsultar" value="Consultar" id="asignarConsultar" onclick="consultarPaciente()">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><div id="paciente"></div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Medico: </td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="medico" name="medico">
                                    <option value="-1" selected="selected">---Seleccione el Medico---</option>
                                    <option value="12345">12345 Camilo Robledo</option>
                                    <option value="67890">67890 Esteban Salgado</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Fecha: </td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Hora: </td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="hora" name="hora">
                                    <option value="-1" selected="selected">---Seleccione la hora---</option>
                                    <option>8:00:00</option>
                                    <option>8:20:00</option>
                                    <option>8:40:00</option>
                                    <option>9:00:00</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Consultorio: </td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="consultorio" name="consultorio">
                                    <option value="-1" selected="selected">---Seleccione el Consultorio---</option>
                                    <option value="1">1 Consultas1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2 Tratamientos2</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <input type="submit" name="asignarEnviar" value="Enviar" id="asignarEnviar">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>    
            </div>    
        </div>
        <!-- ventana modal-->
        <div id="frmPaciente" title="Agregar Nuevo Paciente">
            <form id="agregarPaciente">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Documento</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="pacDocumento" id="pacDocumento" readonly="readonly"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nombres</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="pacNombres" id="pacNombres"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Apellidos</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="pacApellidos" id="pacApellidos"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fecha de Nacimiento</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="pacNacimiento" id="pacNacimiento"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sexo</td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="pacSexo" name="pacSexo">
                                <option value="-1" selected="selected"><---Seleccione Sexo---></option>
                                <option>m</option>
                                <option>f</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<button id="create-user">Create new user</button>
```

Me tomé la libertad de agregar el llamado del dialog en el boton `create-user`

Espero y te sirva, Saludos.

Comment: efectivamente estoy usando una version de jQuery antigua, para crear estos modales solo tengo que vincular  solo esos dos scripts?

Comment: Si, esos scripts son los cdn de jquery y de jquery ui, para poder utilizarlos necesitas esos ademas tmb puedes agregar sus estilos. Puedes tomarlos del sitio oficial de jquery UI

Comment: Muchas gracias fue correcta tu respuesta.

Comment: Me alegra haberte ayudado, un saludo.

Comment: tengo un problema ahora no me esta cargando los estilos, hasta hace un momento funcionaba, pero ya ahora me sale en la esquina inferior izquierda :\

Comment: No entiendo, cuales estilos?, el estilos.css? y como te sale ahora? es que estoy a ciegas.

Comment: voy a poner la imagen

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86346/discussion-between-ricardo-and-jhon-james-hernandez).

Answer (score 0):

Si no me equivoco cuando haces `$(this)` solo esta obteniendo una referencia al boton cerrar, no al modal.

Intenta con:

```
$(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
```

---

> Dejo el codigo, solo modifique el click del boton cerrar.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#frmPaciente').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        heigth: 310,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        buttons: [{
                text: "Crear",
                click: function() {
                    alert("crear");
                }
            },
            {
                text: "Cerrar",
                click: function() {
                    $(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');

                    //$(this).closest('#frmPaciente').dialog('close');

                    //$('#frmPaciente').dialog('close');
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```